# What does the entity_view function do?

Tags: theming, entities

After reading the documentation and searching through code, I can't quite figure out what the entity_view function is for.

The [documentation](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7) explains it executes the view callback if defined, with a fallback to the entity controller's view function. Since I use the EntityAPIController I want to use [that view function](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.controller.inc/function/EntityAPIController%3a%3aview/7), that adds a similar structure like below.

So I assumed entity_view is to replace a structure like this (part of a page callback).

```
// Prepare the entities
entity_prepare_view('entity_type', $entity_field_query_result);

// Apply theme to all entities
foreach($entity_field_query_result as $key => $item) {
  $entity->content = array();
  $entity->content += array(
    '#theme'     => 'my_entity_theme',
    '#element'   => $item,
    '#view_mode' => 'full',
    '#language'  => LANGUAGE_NONE,
  );
  $render[$key] = $entity->content;
}
return $render;
```

Thus I've replaced that with

```
$render = entity_view('entity_type', $entity_field_query_result);

return $render;
```

This however shows an empty page, where the previous function showed me a list of entities. I have custom themes applied to these entities as follows, could that be an issue?

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_entity_theme' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => null),
      'template' => 'my_entity_theme',
      'path' => $path . '/template',
    ),
  );
}
```

So, is my assumption on entity_view correct, or am I missing steps to come to a renderable output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A EntityFieldQuery doesn't return fully loaded entities as result.
Try running the query result through `entity_load('type', $result['type'])`. Then you can render the resulting entites through `entity_view('type', $entities)`.

Here an example:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'article');
$result = $query->execute();
if (!empty($result)) {
  $entities = entity_load('node', array_keys($result['node']));
  return entity_view('node', $entities, 'full');
} else {
  return array('#markup' => t('No article nodes found.'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've written my own query wrapper that in fact does return loaded entities. I read over that when writing the question. So I assume it has to be something else...

Comment: How do the values of $entity_field_query_result look like? Are they renderable? You put them directly in the '#element' field of the render-array - therefore they have to be renderable themself.

Comment: Stupid me - they will be sent to your theme function where you can handle them the way you want.

Comment: So I guess entity_view is not working on your custom theme function. You might dig into that problem: how to use your own theme for certain entity types.

Comment: After dpm'ing the render array I've found out that the entries have `#theme` value of `entity`, where it should be `my_entity_theme`. So the wrong theme is called. I'll see where that goes wrong.

Comment: I've used hook_{entity_type}_view_alter from EntityAPIController to set the #theme parameter to the right value.